# Converting Request.Content to FileStream C#

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I'm trying to receive a file using Web Api from a user and then convert the file into a FileStream without writing the file to a server(Must stay in memory).

I have code that will allow me to write it to the server but all attempts to put it into a FileStream without writing the file to the server have failed.

```
public class ReceiverController : ApiController
{

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;

        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(provider.FileData.First().LocalFileName);
            string fileName = provider.FileData.First().Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(root, fileName)))
            {

                File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, Path.Combine(root, fileName));
            }

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.")
            };
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fileName.PostedFile.InputStream --- gives me Stream and  I use the following code to convert it to byte array. Then byte array is converted to filestream according to the following code.

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileName);
      bytary= br.ReadBytes((Int32)fileName.Length);
            for(int i = 0; i < bytary.Length; i++)
                  {
                         fileStream.WriteByte(bytary[i]);
                                }
```